# (SQL) How to check if a value is in another table?

Tags: sql, join, select

I'm not very good with SQL so I apologise.

I want to be able to go through each row on Table A and check if a specific value exists in an entire column in Table B.

I want to see all rows from table A where value is NOT in specific column in table B.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`. Your question is a bit theorical, the but the logic would be:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
where not exists (select 1 from tableb b where b.col1 = a.col1)
```

Where values in `tabla(col1)` should correspond to values in `tableb(col1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.col = a.col);
```